# Is it possibible to simplify $2^n = 2 \bmod (n(n+1))$ for a calculation with large $n$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

I like to calculate $n$ for the the division $2^n/(n(n+1))$ with the remainder result $2$. This is easy for small $n$, but if I use large $n$, the power of $2$ result is growing very rapid. So it may be that with an intelligent mod calculation to simplfy the formular, especially to avoid the high power of $2$ results or to reduce the exponent with an intelligent mod simplification.

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: This is false for $n=4.$ What are you asking, actually? And wouldn't the Chinese remainder theorem help?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring, also, the sequence is https://oeis.org/A216822.

Comment: Mercy beaucoup Anne :)

Comment: Mercy beaucoup Anne :)
I will check with chinese remainder ...
The solutions to that congruence are 99% primes:
5,13,29,37,61,73,157,181,193,277,313,397,421,457,541,561,613,661,673 ... and 1/18 (5.6 %) of all primes.
So if it's possible to calculate with higher exponents of 2^n via some reduction I can find more of those primes.
Actually it's the same as 2^(n - 1) mod T(n) = 1 with T(n) = TriangularNumbers

Comment: Thanks Pink Rabbit,
this is also very interesting and maybe a way ...